# Durability Problem with ActiveMQ-cpp and stomp

Tags: c++, stomp, hornetq, activemq-cpp, durability

I have a problem creating durable consumers and producers with ActiveMQ-CPP and stomp protocol. I am trying to connect to HornetQ using stomp, and capable of sending and receiving messages in non-durable state. 
I tried changing the producer to durable by setting its delivery mode to persistent along with CMSDeliveryMode of messages as well, and creating a DurableConsumer instead of a normal consumer. But when I looked at JBoss JMX-Console, both of them were considered non-durable (messages are categorized as non-durable, and consumers are subscribed as non-durable as well).

I even tried the integration-test StompDurableTest and only received 10 out of 20 messages (the ones that were sent when the consumer is active). So the test failed.

Since the integration-test didn't work, my guess it has to do with ActiveMQ-cpp or Stomp configurations rather than the code. Am I missing anything to enable durability?

Thanks in Advance,

Sami

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how HornetMQ works but I've seen that others have had issues with the destination names because hornet doesn't like the /topic and /queue prefix that CMS appends in order to work with ActiveMQ.

Another thing to be aware of is that with Stomp your clientId and subscription id need to match, and remain the same each time you connect.

Regards
Tim

www.fusesource.com

Comment: Thanks Tim for the response. I've already changed /queue/ and /topic/ to jms.queue. & jms.topic. from ActiveMQ source, And set subscriptionName to client-id in durability mode but without luck. I can receive successfully when the consumer is active, the problem is when it is subscribed and not active.